# Slow results from Microsoft Graph's list_attachments API and occasionally returns an error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The [`list_attachments`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/message_list_attachments) API is slow to respond and sometimes returns an error message with neither a code nor a description.

To time the API's response, I triggered it 20 times and then recorded the total time and time per API call, both in seconds.

PFB the `python` script used to test the list attachments API.

```
# Initialize variables to track error and success
error_count = 0
success_count = 0

# Allow token scope to not match requested scope. (Other auth libraries allow
# this, but Requests-OAuthlib raises an exception on scope mismatch by default.)
os.environ['OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE'] = '1'

# Define the method to fetch attachments for a message
def fetch_attachment():
    global error_count
    global success_count
    API_ROOT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/'
    API_VERSION = 'v1.0'
    endpoint = API_ROOT + API_VERSION + RESOURCE
    response = msgraph_session.get(endpoint).json()
    if 'error' in response:
        error_count += 1
        LOG.info("Response from the attachments API is %r", response)
    else:
        success_count += 1


# Declare the statement that you want to time
STMT = '''
from __main__ import fetch_attachment
fetch_attachment()
'''

# Run the method and time it
if __name__ == '__main__':
    time = timeit.timeit(STMT, number=20)  # We will run the statement 20 times
    LOG.info("Total time : %s", time)
    LOG.info("Time per call: %s", float(time)/20)
    LOG.info("Error Count %s", error_count)
    LOG.info("Success Count %s", success_count)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2018-08-02 11:36:53,510 - INFO - __main__ - Total time : 407.309007168
2018-08-02 11:36:53,510 - INFO - __main__ - Time per call: 20.3654503584
2018-08-02 11:36:53,511 - INFO - __main__ - Error Count 4
2018-08-02 11:36:53,511 - INFO - __main__ - Success Count 16
```

Out of 20 times, 4 returned the below error message

```
{
   "error":{
      "innerError":{
         "date":"2018-08-02T18:32:27",
         "request-id":"a52a676c-20a6-46c8-a71f-24ce35b166d7"
      },
      "message":"",
      "code":"UnknownError"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

abhi.

According to your information, I suppose you want to call the API `/me/messages/{id}/attachments`. Based on my test, when I add one attachment into the mail, calling this api is not slow.
But when add ten attachments, it's so slow. Because it will response each of the attachments content, so if each of the file is too large, it will be slow.

We can find the part of response like this:

```
{

            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",

            "id": "{attachmentID}",

            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-08-14T07:18:21Z",

            "name": "{attachment name}",

            "contentType": "{attachment type}",

            "contentBytes": ""

 }
```

I think we can use the query parameters to customize responses. We can add the query parameter so that its response does not contain the file content. We can get each `attachment id` by the API like this:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/{message id}/attachments?$select=id,name,size`

Then we can get the content of attachment by the attachment id.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/{message id}/attachments/{attachment id}`